# How to remove rich text editor from user edit page?

Tags: users

I have noticed in user edit page that there is link called rich text editor in all user edit page, I want to remove it. Can anyone tell me how to remove that on user edit page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Better formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_formats) module to show only formats role is authorized to use :